# How to update content(ENML) of Evernote note using Java?

Tags: java, evernote

Is there a way to update the content(ENML) of EN note using Java? Or What I can do is just parse ENML and update ENML, In this case is there a third-party lib to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [updateNote](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_updateNote) method.

1. Get the note
2. Modify what you want
3. Use the updateNote method with your modified note as parameter

I wouldn't suggest parsing the ENML as it's not as trivial as it seems.

---

There's nothing builtin for that. You have to edit the ENML yourself. You can take a look at this gist (it's in python but it might be helpful) gist.github.com/rascode/5468788

Comment: I want to modify the **content** of a note, e.g., add a new line to existing note. But the question here is the content of note is ENML, so how to modify the ENML to append a new line or something else?

Comment: There's nothing builtin for that. You have to edit the ENML yourself.
You can take a look at this gist (it's in python but it might be helpful) https://gist.github.com/rascode/5468788

Comment: It is actually manipulating strings, I will do something like that. Thanks.